# How can I calculate a summation in matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I calculate the analytical function of a function which includes summation, using a for loop.

I have created 3 for loops one for `m` one for `t` and one for `x` but certainly does not work. It gives me inf and not an array of number so that I can plot it. The original formula is:

[image: Original Formula]

```
L=1;
dx=L/N;
N=10;
t_final=0.1;
 dt=0.01;
 D=1;
 sigma=D*dt/(dx^2);
 x=linspace(0,1,N);
 I=eye(N-2);
 B=zeros(N-2,N-2);
 t=0:dt:t_final

for k=1:100
    for j=1:length(t)
        for p=1:length(x)
            C_exact=C_exact+4*((1/((2*k-1)*pi))*exp(-(2*k-1)^2*pi^2*t(j))*sin((2*k-1)*pi*x(p)));
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not working? Have you checked the input values again?

Comment: Where's `m`? Is that `k`? You compute a single `C`, maybe assign to `C_exact(p,j)`?